# Отключить выполнение события у дочернего элемента JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть всплывающее окно, в нем форма. Когда нажимаю вне формы, окно закрывается. Но проблема в том, что и когда нажимаешь на саму форму и ее содержимому так же окно закрывается. Как исправить?

```js
    $('#a').click(function () {
        $('#a').fadeOut(300);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='a'>teg A
      <form id='b'>
        <input type=text/>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Событие `click` на форме и ее содержимом всплывает до элемента `#a`.

```
$('#b').click(function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!